# Firestore Security Rules: Where's hasOnly function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I see `hasOnly` function in some Firestore security rules examples, but I can't find it on the Google's official documents.

What is `hasOnly` function? Has it been already deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

there is hasOnly function here.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasOnly

but it did not work for me :(

i have an issue not solved this thread.
[firestore transaction throws error for update rule which allows only has one specific field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523941/firestore-transaction-throws-error-for-update-rule-which-allows-only-has-one-spe)