# firestore transaction throws error for update rule which allows only has one specific field

Tags: firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

by execution of firestore runTransaction function on the web,
it occurs error below.

firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents:commit:1 POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents:commit 403

i want to allow only update one field for everyone and others are for login user.

so update rule uses next.

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(["numPlayed"]) 
|| request.auth.uid != null;
```

and transaction codes like

```
this.db.runTransaction(function(t) {
    return t.get(pubRef)
    .then(function(pub) {
        var numPlayed = pub.data().numPlayed + 1;
        t.update(pubRef, { numPlayed: numPlayed });
        return numPlayed;
    });
})
```

why it occurs error?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the reason. 
'runTransaction' requires write authority not a divided like update.